# Looking for easy way to show my library's version in storybook

Tags: storybook

I'm trying to add the current version of a project (essentially the `version` field from `package.json`) to storybook so consumers of storybook can tell which version of the project they are looking at. However, I am finding it extremely difficult to do this, I haven't been able to find a way to do it in the config file, and haven't seen any addons that will simply show the current version of the project (other than one that is more made for showing how components have changed over versions, which isn't really what I'm after).

It's easy enough to require the `package.json` file in a js file, and grab the version from there, but storybook seems pretty locked down in terms of allowing you to send any addition information to the header/sidebar.

Has anybody done anything like this before? I'd be grateful for any thoughts or theories on how this could be done. Thanks!

Comment: Any news on this? I'm trying to do the same thing...

Comment: @Finrod I ended up requiring the package json and grabbing the version from there. I was unable to find a way to insert it into storybook, and just put it in another part of our application, sorry!

Answer (score 14):

### Storybook 6

I finally found a "not that bad" solution using the `title` attribute of the `Meta` component in my `.mdx` documentation files:

```
import pkg from '../package.json'
import { Meta } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks'

<Meta title={`Docs ${pkg.version}/Migration Guide`} />
```

[image]

### Storybook 7

This does not work anymore, story title have been made optional and now support only string literals: see [migration guide](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#string-literal-titles)

Answer (score 12):

Also was interested in this question. I've added to `brandTitle` to `.storybook/manager.js` like

```
import { version } from "../package.json"
import { addons } from '@storybook/manager-api'
import { create } from '@storybook/theming'

addons.setConfig({
   theme: create({
       base: "light",
       brandTitle: `My components v.${version}`
   })
})
```

[Theming docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/theming)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But in my case, I had to spend time to figure out what to put where.
First of all, there was no manager.js file. You have to create it.
And second, you need to install all deps. Third, import them.

import { addons } from '@storybook/addons';
import { create } from '@storybook/theming';

Answer (score 2):

I just used the add-on `storybook-version`. From their [docs](https://storybook.js.org/addons/storybook-version):

1. Install: `npm install storybook-version --save-dev`
2. Add to `main.js -> addons` array with `'storybook-version'`
3. Then, in your stories you can add it to your default export params. In the docs these are hard-coded string representation of versioning like `major: '2'` and the like. Below I'm using the version from the package of the component the story is for:

```
...imports...
import { version } from '@my-mono-repo/foo-ponent/package.json';

const [major, minor, patch, postfix] = version.split('.');

export default {
  title: 'FooPonent',
  component: FooPonent,
  ...etc...,
  parameters: {
    componentSubtitle: 'Foo bat blaz bleep bleep',
    ...etc...,
    // the following are the actual version settings
    version: {
      major,
      minor,
      patch,
      postfix,
      style: {
        color: '#fff',
        'font-size': '1rem',
      },
    },
}
```

What it looks like (with what I deemed the style would be in the version params - I've no postfix on this component version):

[image: Where the version shows up]

Answer (score 1):

Since Markdown accepts basic `html` tags, I managed to display the version from `package.json` into a `.mdx` documentation like this:

```
import pkg from '../package.json'

<p>Version: {pkg.version}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

We created "get started" Page contains a brief introduction of our library with the needed steps to integrate the library in angular project.

```
//get-started.stories.mdx
import { Meta, Source } from '@storybook/addon-docs';
import pkg from './components/package.json';

<Meta
  title="General/Get Started"
  parameters={{
    viewMode: 'docs',
    previewTabs: {
      canvas: { hidden: true }
    }
 }}
/>

<Source
 language="shell"
 code={`npm install @my-company/my-lib@${pkg.version}`}
/>

<Source
  language="json"
  format={true}
  code={`
  "dependencies": {
  //...
  "@my-company/my-lib": "${pkg.version}"
  }`}
/>
```

[Source Doc Block](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-docs/doc-block-source#working-with-mdx)