# How can I show custom version of my storybook in the sidebar footer?

Tags: storybook

I want to show a custom version of my storybook in the sidebar footer.
something like this:
[image]

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're interested and I don't think it's possible at this point to do it in the way you want.
Couple of options are: [Looking for easy way to show my library's version in storybook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60550641/looking-for-easy-way-to-show-my-librarys-version-in-storybook)
Another is to use the version selector plugin:
https://storybook.js.org/addons/@panosvoudouris/addon-versions